# Who placed the crucifix under Regan's pillow in The Exorcist?

Tags: the-exorcist

In "The Exorcist", Regan's mother Chris finds a crucifix under the girl's pillow and asks each member of the household staff if they placed the crucifix there. Is it revealed anywhere in the film how the crucifix got there?

Answer (score 4):

It is not revealed anywhere in the movie who put it there, but in the book it was hinted that Regan put it there herself between possessions.  I'll see if I can find the book and point to a specific page and passage, it's been a while since I read it.